# Defining active expanded state in jQuery UI Accordion

Tags: jquery, html, css

Probably terribly simple, but how could I define which area in my accordion is expanded and active and which one is isn't?

I have it setup in the simpliest form directly from the UI/API/1.8/Accordion Page

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion();
  });

  </script>

<div id="accordion">

<h3><a href="#">Section 1</a></h3>

<h3><a href="#">Section 2</a></h3>

</div>
```

I only have two sections, by default with the code the top first section is expanded. I want to have the second one expanded by default, and the first collapsed.

This has got to be so easy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({ active: 2 });
```

shoul make the second active and then you ca activate any you want by changing 2

Comment: Add that to the line right under 'ready(function)'? I just tried it, and now neither are expanded by default?

Comment: Set it to 1: `$( "#accordion" ).accordion({ active: 1 });`. First element is 0. http://jsfiddle.net/2rydd/1/